# Why is unity smoothing the axis (vertical, horizontal) values not as expected?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

I want to implement character movement using Character Controller.

I have set up an animator that takes 2 values `horizontal` and `vertical` (from -1 to 1).

Based on these values, it animates movement in different directions.

But I ran into a certain problem. If I press I press the key opposite to the movement (for example a -> d or w -> s) then my animation is slightly interrupted.

I use methods :

```
Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
```

they smooth the value from 0 to 1, or from -1 to 0. But if I change the movement abruptly, I get the following (for example -1, 0, 0.1, 0.2 ... 1)

How to correct this correctly?

Comment: define "correct" ;) You can always use [`GetAxisRaw`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html) instead and smooth/interpolate yourself ...

Comment: a key is down or its not, its not a joystick where there are degrees of movement

Comment: @derHugo I expect that it will smooth values from -1 to 1, and not make a jump from -1 to 0, but from 0 to 1 it will start smoothing (as it does now).

Comment: @BugFinder I think what OP is referring to is that the jump `-1` -> `0` is way faster than the later smoothed `0` -> `+1`

Comment: But yeah as said .. use `GetAxisRaw` instead and do the smoothing yourself (e.g. using [`SmoothDamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothDamp.html) or maybe even simply [`MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.MoveTowards.html) etc .. depending on your desired smoothing behavior)

Comment: And yeah the behavior with snapping to `0` is indeed "expected" / part of `GetAxis` as well as holding down both keys at the same time cancels them out